# how does google-chrome match cached youtube video with the player

Tags: caching, google-chrome, youtube, flash

I am on ubuntu 11.04 and chrome caches youtube videos in `.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/` folder with a pattern like `f_00b3`. I looked at the html source of the youtube page to figure out how the browser decides on and remembers a cache file name to store and playback the video, but I could not find anything.

Does anyone know how this works and how I can access this information with some shell scripts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you have "\" folder separators on Ubuntu? You better change that before someone notices ;)

Comment: If you google "chrome cache file" a bunch of pages with utilities and hints turn up.